# External hosts wildcard phonegap IOS

Tags: xcode, cordova, app-store, wildcard

Hi all i'm almost ready to send my app to app store and a question came up!
In few words i call a remote php file via ajax and retrive infos from a database, in which i'll have some external link i would like to show in my app (like productors web sites).
The problem is: to let the user open the external links i have to put a * in my phonegap.plist externalhosts field. i would like to know if this will cause a reject from app store for my app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no you're fine, thats the way it has to be done for native apps as well. I have had apps get accepted that use the same thing. :)